# What determines which projects in VisualStudio are consider to be publish artifacts in Azure Devops Build

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-build-task

I have a solution with multiple projects(.NET). Most of them Web applications and one Console Application.

I have created a new solution configuration in Visual Studio called QA.

On my Azure DevOps CI Build I have set up my BuildConfiguration to QA.

Everything builds but when I check in my Publish Artifact I don't see my Console Application project artifact.

Anybody else having this issue ?

What determines what projects get publish as an Artifact ?

Thanks In advance[image: Build publish artifacts log]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default the console application project will not be published to artifact as There isn't any project specific setup required to generate the `exe` and release files for the console application in build artifact directory.

However if you want to include the Console Application in the artifact, you just need to add a **Copy Files** step to copy the Console Application to the `$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)`. Of course you need to firstly make sure you have built the Console Application project and the `.exe` file generated successfully.

> **Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory**
>
> The local path on the agent where any artifacts are copied to before
>   being pushed to their destination. For example: c:\agent_work\1\a.
>
> A typical way to use this folder is to publish your build artifacts
>   with the [Copy files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/tasks/utility/copy-files?view=vsts) and Publish build artifacts steps.

You can also build the Console Application separately with `MSBuild` task, and `VisualStudioBuild` task to build the rest of the applications.

[image]